# How to Read IndexedDB on a Remote Machine?

Tags: javascript, browser, internet-explorer-11

I'd like to read the IndexedDB for Internet Explorer on a remote machine.  I have admin access to this remote machine.

How can I connect to a remote IndexedDB on a remote machine and read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexedDB follows a same-origin policy. So while you can access stored data within a domain, you cannot access data across different domains. More details about how to use IndexedDB, please check these articles： [IndexedDB Basic concepts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB), [Indexed Database API](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#database-connection) and [Using IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB)